# Create a new column in pandas depending on values from two other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an example data as:

```
datetime    column1.   column2 
2020-01-01.   5.       [0,0,0,1]
2020-01-02.   4.       [0,0,0,0]
2020-01-03.   10.      [1,1,1,0]
2020-01-04.   2.       [1,1,1,1]
```

I want a new column called action which assumes: 1 if column1 values are below 3 and above 5 otherwise the df.column2.any(axis=1) values.

The example output should look like this:

```
datetime    column1.   column2    action
2020-01-01.   5.       [0,0,0,1].  1
2020-01-02.   2.       [0,0,0,0].  1
2020-01-03.   10.      [1,1,1,0].  1
2020-01-04.   4.       [0,0,0,0]   0
```

Comment: I'm not sure how a value can be below 3 AND above 5, but you should try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369929/creating-a-new-column-based-on-the-values-of-other-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) with `any`:

```
df['action'] = np.where(df.column1.between(3,5), df.column2.apply(any), 1)
print (df)
     datetime  column1       column2  action
0  2020-01-01        5  [0, 0, 0, 1]       1
1  2020-01-02        2  [0, 0, 0, 0]       1
2  2020-01-03       10  [1, 1, 1, 0]       1
3  2020-01-04        4  [0, 0, 0, 0]       0
```

Comment: the column 1 with value 4 should return an action of 0 and not 1

Comment: @StackUser - soory, I chaneg data, give me a sec.

Comment: i meant if the values are below 3 and above 5 it should return 1, but 4 is between the two values so it should return df.column2.apply(any) which is 0.

Comment: below 3..it means values like 2 then action should return 1

Comment: @StackUser - Super, so if first row is `[0,0,0,0]` then is `0`, because for 5 is used `any`, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly the case